# How customize data of EntityType with repository

Tags: php, symfony, repository, symfony4

I want to get customize choices from a FormType

This is is the FormType:

```
builder->add('demandes', EntityType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une option',
            'class'    => DemandeCandidats::class,
            'mapped' => false,
        ])
```

And this the repository

```
public function findActif($value)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('d')
        ->andWhere('d.etat = :val')
        ->setParameter('val', "actif")
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

How to add this repository to EntityType ?

Comment: Read about it here https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
builder->add('demandes', EntityType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une option',
            'class'    => DemandeCandidats::class,
            'mapped' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityTypeRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                           ->andWhere('d.etat = :val')
                           ->setParameter('val', "actif")
                           ->getQuery()
                           ->getResult();
                    },
        ])
```

Or

```
builder->add('demandes', EntityType::class, [
            'placeholder' => 'Choisissez une option',
            'class'    => DemandeCandidats::class,
            'mapped' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityTypeRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findActif("actif");
                    },
        ])
```